# Error in google map loading

Tags: android, google-maps

I got this crash when Try to start any map activity ..

this is my gradle dependencies:
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.1'

compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.3'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'


}
```

this is logcat

```
11-05 10:00:19.603 10285-10285/com.wneet.white E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.wneet.white, PID: 10285
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wneet.white/com.wneet.white.LoadingFirst}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at com.wneet.white.LoadingFirst.onCreate(LoadingFirst.java:88)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5581)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanx in advance.

Comment: put your activity code and logcat

Comment: how can I put the logcat ?
it is my first question here ^_^

Comment: when you got an error the error will show up in android monitor tab which is the logcat, then just copy the error here. and before that put your activity code here

Comment: I think the problem isn't from activity couze It was working fine :(

Comment: just put it here please

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure that you were able to set up your project with a compatible Google Play services SDK as discussed in [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). If you haven't installed the Google Play services SDK yet, go get it now by following the guide to [Adding SDK Packages](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html).

Solutions given in this [blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/715351/Google-MAP-API-V-unable-to-load) and [GitHub post](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7915) might also give you possible workaround and might help.